# How to display a variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to locate a user by his/her ip address and I'm using the Gem GeoIP ... now everything functions right but how do I pull their city or state and display that or put it into another area of a controller. So far I've got;

```
def user_location

    GeoIP.geolocation('209.85.227.104')

end
```

Now doing this, pulls all information of that IP;

```
=> {:ip=>"209.85.227.104", :status_code=>"OK", :status_message=>"", :country_code=>"US", :country_name=>"UNITED STATES", :region_name=>"CALIFORNIA", :city=>"MONTEREY PARK", :zip_code=>"91754", :latitude=>"34.0625", :longitude=>"-118.123"}
```

Now I've tried doing;

user_location.region_name

but I get nothing... I know I'm close and I'm missing something within the above line... maybe the `@` in `user_location`

I've searched and search end sort of get it but nothing comes close to what I'd like...

Comment: Try `user_location[:region_name]`.

Comment: awesome that worked. :) I should of thought of it as an object .... `[:region_name]` is an object correct?

Comment: Everything in a ruby is an object.  However, this is a `Hash` with symbol keys.  `{:key => 'value'}` is simply how hashes are declared and displayed.